# SharedObject (flash) equivalent?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, unity-game-engine

With **Flash** I can use `SharedObject` to store images. In **Unity** (webplayer) what is the equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the image, you can store it in [`PlayerPrefs`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

You'll have to convert the image byte array to a String first, though.

Comment: About 300kb each. But there are like 20 images to save.

Comment: Sorry, `PlayerPrefs` can only store up to 1 MB per Web Player URL, so that won't work.